# Gmail addon createdraftreply() replying to yourself

Tags: google-apps-script

I am referencing the official guide 
[here](https://developers.google.com/gmail/add-ons/how-tos/compose)

to create a reply draft.

```
  var composeAction = CardService.newAction()
      .setFunctionName('createReplyDraft');
  var composeButton = CardService.newTextButton()
      .setText('Compose Reply')
      .setComposeAction(composeAction, CardService.ComposedEmailType.REPLY_AS_DRAFT);

  // ...

  /**
   *  Creates a draft email (with an attachment and inline image)
   *  as a reply to an existing message.
   *  @param {Object} e data passed by the compose action.
   *  @return {ComposeActionResponse}
   */
  function createReplyDraft(e) {
    // Activate temporary Gmail add-on scopes, in this case to allow
    // a reply to be drafted.
    var accessToken = e.messageMetadata.accessToken;
    GmailApp.setCurrentMessageAccessToken(accessToken);

    // Creates a draft reply.
    var messageId = e.messageMetadata.messageId;
    var message = GmailApp.getMessageById(messageId);
    var draft = message.createDraftReply('',
        {
            htmlBody: "Kitten! <img src='cid:kitten'/>",
            attachments: [
              UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://example.com/images/myDog.jpg')
                  .getBlob()
            ],
            inlineImages: {
              "kitten": UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://example.com/images/myKitten.jpg')
                           .getBlob()
            }
        }
    );

    // Return a built draft response. This causes Gmail to present a
    // compose window to the user, pre-filled with the content specified
    // above.
    return CardService.newComposeActionResponseBuilder()
        .setGmailDraft(draft).build();
  }
```

It works fine when the last message in the thread is from the other person,
but when the last message is from yourself,
the recipient address of the new draft is your address, not the other person.

1.

(Last message) Other person → Me

createDraftReply()

(Draft) Me → Other person

2.

(Last message) Me → Other person

createDraftReply()

(Draft) **Me → Me**

How can I create a reply draft with the right recipient?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before creating a reply draft check whether the TO address is self or not.
If TO is self, create reply all draft instead of reply draft
Else create reply draft.

```
if(message.getTo() === Session.getEffectiveUser().getEmail())
```

This is how you can check.

OR

There is one more way, you can iterate over all emails and pick the latest mail from the outsider and create a reply draft for it.

```
var mssgs = message.getThread().getMessages();
```

Comment: By using the replyAll the "to" field is still set to the "me" address but a "cc" with the recipient of the message is added. On the second case, it would only work for threads that have incoming mails. If the only existing mails were sent by the user it would not be possible to do that.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I've considered and tried both and I ended up going with the replyAll option.

Answer (score 0):

Was banging my head with this one and eventually found a workaround.

The idea is to create an **empty** `createDraftReplyAll` and then use `.update()` from GMAILDraft to set the new recipients.

Below is somw ugly code, but hopefully, it can help. In my case, I have multiple email addresses under the same gmail account, so I also loop through a "ME_ALIAS".

```
var accessToken = e.gmail.accessToken;
GmailApp.setCurrentMessageAccessToken(accessToken);

var htmlEmailBody = "All good?";
var messageId = e.gmail.messageId;
var message = GmailApp.getMessageById(messageId);
var lastMessage = message.getThread().getMessages().pop();

// Get all recipients (To and Cc) from the last message as a string.
var lastRecipientsString = lastMessage.getTo() + "," + lastMessage.getFrom();
if(lastMessage.getCc()) {
  lastRecipientsString += ","+lastMessage.getCc();
}

//create empty draft reply
var draft = message.createDraftReplyAll('');

// Parse the recipients string into an array of email addresses.
var lastRecipients = lastRecipientsString.split(',');

// Create an array of email addresses to add to the "To" field.
var toRecipients = [];
for (var i = 0; i < lastRecipients.length; i++) {
  var isMe = false;
  for (var j = 0; j < ME_ALIAS.length; j++) {
    if (lastRecipients[i].indexOf(ME_ALIAS[j]) !== -1) {
      isMe = true;
      break;
    }
  }
  if (!isMe) {
    toRecipients.push(lastRecipients[i]);
  }
}


// Get the current draft message body, subject, and recipient.
var currentMessage = draft.getMessage();
var currentSubject = currentMessage.getSubject();

// Modify the draft email to set the other person's email as the "To" field.
draft.update(toRecipients.join(','), currentSubject, null, {
    cc: '',
    bcc: '',
    htmlBody: htmlEmailBody
});

CardService.newComposeActionResponseBuilder().setGmailDraft(draft).build();
```